# Determine the ranges for sums and differences of two angles

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, angle

Suppose that $\alpha \in [\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ and $\beta \in [\beta_1,\beta_2)$ are two angles. In this case, what will be the ranges of $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha-\beta$?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, tried to formulate the question, but the first formulation was not correct. Please check my updated question.

Comment: $a_1<a<a_2$ and $b_1<b<b_2$, sum both inequalities to get $a_1+b_1<a+b<a_2+b_2$. Can you find the rule for $?<a-b<?$ ? Tip: once you've written it, substitute the intervals with some numbers to see if it checks out.

Comment: And remember how the minus sign influences the inequalities sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\alpha_1 \le \alpha < \alpha_2$ and $\beta_1 \leq \beta \lt \beta_2$. From the range of $\beta$ we get that $-\beta_1 \geq -\beta >-\beta_2$.

Adding the first two inequalitis gives $\alpha_1+\beta_1 \leq \alpha+\beta < \alpha_2+\beta_2$, or $\alpha+\beta\in [\alpha_1+\beta_1, \alpha_2+\beta_2)$.

Similarly, the first and third inequalities imply $\alpha-\beta \in (\alpha_1-\beta_2, \alpha_2-\beta_1)$.